# Callback function for toggle, seems like it execute before toggle is done

Tags: jquery, html

I'm doing a callback for my `toggle`, It seems it executes before the `toggle` is done. Is there something I could do to prevent that? or do I just "reverse" my `if`

jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5R7Nf/1/)

```
$('#toggle_now').change(function () {
    $('#show_me').toggle(!this.checked, callBack());
}).change();

function callBack() {
    var $this = $('#show_me');
    if (!$this.is(':visible')) {
        $('#span_me').html('visible');
    } else {
        $('#span_me').html('hidden');        
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I kinda need the option off `ShowAndHide`, can I achieve a `callback function` without creating a new function that keeps listening to the toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when using the "**showOrhide**" option in toggle, it has **no callback** !!!

You need a duration for that, as that is the only time the toggle function would be asynchronous:

```
$('#toggle_now').on('change', function () {
    $('#show_me').toggle(this.checked);
    $('#span_me').html($('#show_me').is(':visible') ?  'visible' : 'hidden');
}).change();​
```

There's no need for a callback, as the `html()` function will not execute until after the `toggle()` function is completed anyway.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3ADNg/2/)

Comment: great answer, i edited my question a bit, i would like to keep the `ShowAndHide`

Answer (score 1):

You are binding a call to the function rather than the function itself.  Change to:

```
.toggle(!this.checked, callBack); //no parentheses
```

EDIT: There is actually another problem; the [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method doesn't work that way when accepting a `boolean` argument.  Instead, remove that first argument and reverse your `if`:

http://jsfiddle.net/5R7Nf/3/

Comment: If i do that then it wont reference to the function at all

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
$('#toggle_now').change(function () {
    $('#show_me').toggle(!this.checked, callBack);
}).change();
```